# New window from link WITH popup

Tags: hyperlink, popup, window

Tried searching around but can't seem to find a straight forward answer to what I'm trying to do...

I need to create a link that opens a new page WITH a unique popup. I don't want to simply embed a popup plugin for that new page. The link is the only method that the popup should be seen on the new page.

Does this make sense and how can I achieve it?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html

have a look on this this is exactaly same...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this is just a simple popup plugin that is launched from an href or other element. I need an href that launches a new page (just like a normal link) but also launches a popup ONLY WHEN that link is clicked.

Comment: or you can use <a href="www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">yourlink</a> but it behave different in all browsers internet explorer can open in new window and firefox in new tab

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I'm trying to do as this is not a solution. Again, link should go to a new page that also has a popup within that page. Thanks though.

Comment: the new target page should have markup plugin or java script to open the popup as you know http is stateless.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jex5.htm','mywindow','width=400,height=200')">yourlink</a>
```

this is simple java script that can open new window